# Set Multiple HTML Attributes Using Class Attributes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been able to achieve certain success with the following code to target id attributes using JavaScript to set multiple attributes:

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}
setAttributes(svgShape,{'d':complexShape,'fill':'#f04'});
```

However, would it be possible to use that code or a similar code to target class attributes, not id attributes?

Comment: Do you mean if the element has been fetched by ID vs by Class?

Comment: Hi @fatRaspberry if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the elements by their classname they come as an HTML element collection, therefore you must convert the class elements into an array and then iterate through them or use an Array call with a foreach:

**Conversion to Array**

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  var elements = [].slice.call(el);
  elements.forEach(function(element){
    for(var key in attrs) {
      element.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  });
  }
}
```

**Prototype Calling**

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  [].forEach.call(el,function(element){
    for(var key in attrs) {
      element.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
    }
  });
}
```